# Average of month ratio vs previous year

Tags: descriptive-statistics

I can't figure out if it's possible to calculate the **`3.125`** average of monthly ratio without dividing on each month. 
I mean only using the year totals or year average or some aggregate of year instead of month.

I tried (total of 2018)/ (total of 2017) and avg(2018)/avg(2017) but I don't get the correct result.

```
Month   2017    2018    2018/2017
1         10      50       5
2         20      60       3
3         30      75      2.5
4         40      80       2
    avg of (5,3,2.5,2)   3.125

sum       100    265      2.65 (265/100)
avg        25    66.25    2.65 (66.25/25)
```

I am bad at math so please be kind :))

Comment: Note that dividing 2018 value / 2017 value represents a ratio and NOT "the monthly increase" as you say. A monthly increase comes from difference not division. Be very specific at what you want to know, the the calculation could be determined later.

Comment: Thank you, I adjusted the question

Comment: The results are different because $\dfrac {(A+B+C+D)}{(a+b+c+d)} \ne (\dfrac A a + \dfrac B b + \dfrac C c + \dfrac D d)$

Comment: As said, the 2 calculations are different. In general, regardless of the specific values (unless all are equal), The average of the sums is not arithmetically equal to the sum of averages.

Comment: @Mauro ALLEGRANZA 40 and 106 it was supposed to be average of year but it was wrong, sorry I adjusted the question.

Comment: Ok I can see they are different, what I am asking is there any formula that doesn't involve using each month values and only using year totals to reach the 3.125?

Comment: Short answer : NO.

Comment: If you insist on your calculation method, use a spreadsheet.